# Windows 10 font size in modal windows

Tags: windows-10, display, fonts

For some time I have a problem in windows 10. Most of modal windows have weirdly big font. All is fine, except of these modals. Here two examples:

resharper modal - the input font is OK, everything else is huge
[image: resharper modal]

sql management studio - modal big, left section normal
[image: sql management studio]
[image: sql management studio]

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally resolved it!

Here is full thread from [MS Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6a20007c-e6cd-401f-b703-51d9ac80cf57/windows-10-font-size-differs-in-some-applications-on-the-computer?forum=win10itprogeneral#a9233513-9c7d-40f4-a7e9-e953e7fc987e)

...TLDR...

It was connected to display scaling in windows. I don't own HDPI display, but I changed it up to 125%, then back to 100%, rebooted and it's OK.

If you have HDPI display, checkout this [link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/spaghettidba/2015/10/14/ssms-in-high-dpi-displays-how-to-stop-the-madness/) for workaround.